# TypeError: cannot concatenate object of type '<class 'str'>'; only Series and DataFrame objs are valid. It was supposed to work with df.append

Tags: pandas, dataframe, google-vision

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['locale', 'description']) 
for text in texts:
    df = pd.concat(
        dict(
            locale=text.locale,
            description=text.description
        ),
        ignore_index=True
    )
```

Are there any workaround for this? It was supposed to work with df.append but it says FutureWarning: The frame.append method is deprecated and will be removed from pandas in a future version. Use pandas.concat instead.

Comment: Please add a sample of your dataframe.

Comment: Do `df = pd.DataFrame({'locale': [t.locale for t in texts], 'description': [t.description for t in texts]})`.